# Apache Beam Coder for GenericRecord

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, avro, apache-beam

I am building a pipeline that reads Avro generic records. To pass GenericRecord between stages I need to register AvroCoder. The documentation says that if I use generic record, the schema argument can be arbitrary: https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/coders/AvroCoder.html#of-java.lang.Class-org.apache.avro.Schema-

However, when I pass an empty schema to the method `AvroCoder.of(Class, Schema)` it throws an exception at run time. Is there a way to create an AvroCoder for GenericRecord that does not require a schema? In my case, each GenericRecord has an embedded schema.

The exception and stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.AvroCoder$AvroDeterminismChecker.checkIndexedRecord(AvroCoder.java:562)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.AvroCoder$AvroDeterminismChecker.recurse(AvroCoder.java:430)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.AvroCoder$AvroDeterminismChecker.check(AvroCoder.java:409)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.AvroCoder.<init>(AvroCoder.java:260)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.AvroCoder.of(AvroCoder.java:141)
```

Comment: What is the exception that is thrown?

Comment: @KennKnowles Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.AvroCoder$AvroDeterminismChecker.checkIndexedRecord(AvroCoder.java:562)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.AvroCoder$AvroDeterminismChecker.recurse(AvroCoder.java:430)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.AvroCoder$AvroDeterminismChecker.check(AvroCoder.java:409)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.AvroCoder.<init>(AvroCoder.java:260)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.AvroCoder.of(AvroCoder.java:141)

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar case and solved it with custom coder. The simplest (but sub-efficient) solution would be to encode schema along with each record. If your schemas are not too volatile you can get benefit of caching.

```
public class GenericRecordCoder extends AtomicCoder<GenericRecord> {
    public static GenericRecordCoder of() {
        return new GenericRecordCoder();
    }
    private static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, AvroCoder<GenericRecord>> avroCoders = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void encode(GenericRecord value, OutputStream outStream) throws IOException {
        String schemaString = value.getSchema().toString();
        String schemaHash = getHash(schemaString);
        StringUtf8Coder.of().encode(schemaString, outStream);
        StringUtf8Coder.of().encode(schemaHash, outStream);
        AvroCoder<GenericRecord> coder = avroCoders.computeIfAbsent(schemaHash, 
            s -> AvroCoder.of(value.getSchema()));
        coder.encode(value, outStream);
    }

    @Override
    public GenericRecord decode(InputStream inStream) throws IOException {
        String schemaString = StringUtf8Coder.of().decode(inStream);
        String schemaHash = StringUtf8Coder.of().decode(inStream);
        AvroCoder<GenericRecord> coder = avroCoders.computeIfAbsent(schemaHash, 
             s -> AvroCoder.of(new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaString)));
        return coder.decode(inStream);
    }
}
```

While this solves the task, in fact I made it slightly different, using external schema registry (you can build this on the top of datastore for example). In this case you don't need to serialize/deserialize schema. The code looks like:

```
public class GenericRecordCoder extends AtomicCoder<GenericRecord> {
    public static GenericRecordCoder of() {
        return new GenericRecordCoder();
    }
    private static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, AvroCoder<GenericRecord>> avroCoders = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void encode(GenericRecord value, OutputStream outStream) throws IOException {
        SchemaRegistry.registerIfAbsent(value.getSchema());
        String schemaName = value.getSchema().getFullName();
        StringUtf8Coder.of().encode(schemaName, outStream);
        AvroCoder<GenericRecord> coder = avroCoders.computeIfAbsent(schemaName, 
            s -> AvroCoder.of(value.getSchema()));
        coder.encode(value, outStream);
    }

    @Override
    public GenericRecord decode(InputStream inStream) throws IOException {
        String schemaName = StringUtf8Coder.of().decode(inStream);
        AvroCoder<GenericRecord> coder = avroCoders.computeIfAbsent(schemaName, 
             s -> AvroCoder.of(SchemaRegistry.get(schemaName)));
        return coder.decode(inStream);
    }
}
```

The usage is pretty straightforward:

```
PCollection<GenericRecord> inputCollection = pipeline
    .apply(AvroIO
           .parseGenericRecords(t -> t)
           .withCoder(GenericRecordCoder.of())
           .from(...));
```

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing the code for `AvroCoder`, I do not think the documentation is correct there. Your `AvroCoder` instance will need a way to figure out the schema for your Avro records - and likely the only way to do that is by providing one.

So, I'd recommend calling `AvroCoder.of(GenericRecord.class, schema)`, where `schema` is the correct schema for the `GenericRecord` objects in your PCollection.